how to read excel file form google drive in python
sir
see my simple  code for read the excel file form google drive but it give me the error
pleas see my code and give me the idea
import pandas as pd
url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j5nNupNht5CJMCUTyBsmx0bU_1UMeBjQ02dY_eUNqrU/edit?usp=sharing"
url_for_pandas = url.replace("/edit?usp=share_link", "/export?format=xlsx")
#df = pd.read_excel(f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id={sheet_id}&format=xlsx") is also not working 
df = pd.read_excel(url_for_pandas)
print(df)

error
 raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
PS C:\mainfol\mfatt> 

raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
PS C:\mainfol\mfatt>

You need to ensure the file is publicly accessible or shared with anyone with the link. In Drive, under "Get link", set it to "Anyone with the link" and copy the link provided. Modify this link to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/export?format=xlsx by replacing /edit?usp=sharing with /export?format=xlsx.

This is the wrong way to go about it. Use google's api as documented here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/
